# hreflang tag to be added on each page of the website or only on homepage?

Tags: seo, multilingual, hreflang, homepage

I'm planning to add `hreflang` attribute to my websites which are in different languages, including my main website which is in English. So I have few questions regarding this.

1. Is the `hreflang` attribute to be added only on the homepage or shall I add it on every page?
2. On every language version of my website I shall mention all other website using `hreflang` like this?

   [image: HTML source code showing link elements with hreflang and rel-alternate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every page with an alternate. This is clearly stated in the [specification](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en):

> rel="alternate" hreflang="x" is used as a **page level, not a site level**, and you need to mark up each set of pages, including the home page, as appropriate.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GDav, Could you please share some insight second point of my question?

Comment: @Sanchit I'm not clear what you're looking for with the second point: it's a statement, not a question. Can you clarify?